# How to create an associated token account in solana using the token-2022 program

Tags: solana, solana-program-library

How do you create an associated token account in Solana for a token-2022?

```js
function getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
    mint: PublicKey,
    owner: PublicKey,
    allowOwnerOffCurve = false,
    programId = TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    associatedTokenProgramId = ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
): PublicKey {
    if (!allowOwnerOffCurve && !PublicKey.isOnCurve(owner.toBuffer())) throw new TokenOwnerOffCurveError();

    const [address] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
        [owner.toBuffer(), programId.toBuffer(), mint.toBuffer()],
        associatedTokenProgramId
    );

    return address;
}
```

The solana-program-library js lib only seems to have examples using the regular TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `programId` to `TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID`?